# How do I put a file path variable into pandas.read_csv?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, operating-system, environ

I tried to apply it through os.environ like so:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

os.environ["FILE"] = "File001"

df = pd.read_csv('/path/$FILErawdata.csv/')
```

But pandas doesn't recognize `$FILE` and instead gives me **$FILErawdata.csv not found**

Is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

#### New Answer:

If you like string interpolation, python now uses [f-strings for string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

filename = "File001"

df = pd.read_csv(f'/path/{filename}rawdata.csv/')
```

#### Old Answer:

Python doesn't use variables like shells scripts do. Variables don't get automatically inserted into strings.

To do this, you have to create a string with the variable inside.

Try this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

filename = "File001"

df = pd.read_csv('/path/' + filename + 'rawdata.csv/')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_csv('/path/%(FILE)srawdata.csv' % os.environ)
```

I suspect you need to remove the trailing '/'.